# How to use Scrollmagic and GSAP in REACT project

Tags: reactjs, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm following using this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w7jvzxo9w?from-embed) as a guide with my React project and receiving this error:

> ./node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'TimelineMax'

Assuming I copied everything from that sandbox to my local files, why am I getting that error?

I'm using Create-react-app btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### animation.gsap.js requires TimelineMax module so try importing 'TimelineMax' module

```
import { TimelineMax} from 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js';
```

also you can refer to [github solution](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/issues/685#issuecomment-314771153)

Comment: Adding the import didn't work however following the github solution link you provided did the trick. The hard part was finding the file. If anyone is wondering it's located at 'myprojectpath\node_modules\react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js'